# Eclipse, RED Robot Editor & keywords

Tags: eclipse, selenium

I'm using the Eclipse IDE with the RED Robot Editor for my Robot Framework test automation. Is it possible to enable a feature so that when I begin typing in Selenium2Library keywords, I get a list of items to choose. PyCharm has this feature, however, Eclipse seems like a much better IDE. I believe this is also called "smart editing features to support the Robot Framework". If RED doesn't support this feature, are there other plugins that do?

Answer (score 0):

Content assistant: Just like other modern Developments Environments, RED supports content assistance/code completion. When editing tab or item in text editor, press CTRL+SPACE keys to activate hints for robot keywords an variables.